# Complex lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a worksheet which contains a list of parameters 'Parameters':

```
A            | B            | C          | D        | E          |
Manufacturer | Item Type    | Price From | Price To | Percentage |
Apple        | Mobile Phone | 0.00       | 99.99    | 50%        |
Apple        | Mobile Phone | 100.00     | 149.99   | 45%        |
Apple        | Tablet       | 0.00       | 99.99    | 65%        |
```

I have another worksheet which contains a list of retail items 'Retail Stock':

```
A            | B            | C              | D            |
Manufacturer | Item Type    | Purchase Price | Retail Price |
Apple        | Mobile Phone | 80.00          | ?            |
Apple        | Mobile Phone | 120.00         | ?            |
Apple        | Tablet       | 95.00          | ?            |
```

What I need to do in column D of 'Retail Stock' Worksheet, I need to pull back the relevant Percentage from the parameters worksheet in order to work out the Retail Price.

To find the percentage I need to do a lookup on Parameters worksheet, passing Manufacturer, Item Type and Purchase Price.

Please can someone advise on this,
I appreciate my question may need more padding to get the right answer, so if you need any more information, please ask.

Comment: 1) `Purchase Price` should be between `Price From` and `Price To`? 2) is it possible to have two or more records in `Parameters` sheet matching single item in `Retail Stock` sheet?

Comment: Hi 1) Yes, Purchase price should fall in the range of Price From & Price To. 2) There will only ever be one match, there will be no overlap in parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(Parameters!E:E,Parameters!A:A,A2,Parameters!B:B,B2,Parameters!C:C,"<="&C2,Parameters!D:D,">="&C2)
```

I don't think there can be overlaps in prices as this wouldn't make much sense to me, so the above should give you the appropriate percentage.

Format as appropriate.

Note: If there is no match, then the function will return `0`.

---

`SUMIFS` will take the sum from the column `E` of Parameters, provided that:

- Column A is equal to A2,
- Column B is equal to B2,
- Column C is below C2,
- Column D is above C2

Comment: Hi. I get 0 back every time, am I missing something?

Comment: @Richard Could it be that there are spaces in the `Manufacturer` and/or `Item` fields? Ensure that you also have automatic calculation on (or press F9 to recalculate).

Comment: slight amendment to your query solved it, needed <= & >=:

=SUMIFS(Parameters!E:E,Parameters!A:A,A2,Parameters!B:B,B2,Parameters!C:C,"<="&C2,Parameters!D:D,">="&C2) 


Many Thanks.

Comment: @Richard Oh, oops. Yes, if you have amounts on the borders, `<` and `>` won't be working...

Answer (score 1):

> here will only ever be one match, there will be no overlap in parameters

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Parameters!$A$2:$A$100=A2)*
            (Parameters!$B$2:$B$100=B2)*
            (C2>=Parameters!$C$2:$C$100)*
            (C2<=Parameters!$D$2:$D$100)*
            (Parameters!$E$2:$E$100)
           )
```

for non matching rows formula returns `0`